# How do I limit the classes that are securable by spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have noticed that the startup time on my app is getting brutally slow. One problem is that spring security is scanning the entire classpath including my dependant jars for classes that might be annotated with secure annotations.  As the maintainer of this code, I feel confident only my particular package 'com.company' will need to be secured?  Is this an option in spring?

Comment: No, mainly because Spring Security itself doesn't do any classpath scanning to look for secured annotations. You'll need to describe in more detail what you are observing that makes you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined a base-package in your Spring config?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany"/>
```

Comment: that does not affect spring security available classes, because I can secure classes outside the scope of that component-scan